# How to find running processes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to cycle through the active processes on the system and find when my program starts? It has the name 'Calculate Distance' as the form1.vb text.

There fore, I want to be able to close a splash screen when the form1 loads. This requires checking currently running processes. How do I do that in VB.NET 2005?

Thanks in advance,

Catcalls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Process.GetProcessesByName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) method in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

```
bool processIsRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("THE NAME OF YOUR PROCSS").Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this easy code snipit  VB 2010

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO    

If Process.GetProcessesByName("name of process without .extension").Length > 0 Then
                chekrun = 3
            Else
                chekrun = 10
            End If
```